# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (3,1)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-regression

Im working on a linear regression coding problem and i get this error on trying to code the feature matrix part. can you please help me correct this ?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, 
>   in runTest
>      self.test(*self.arg)
>   File "C:\Users\visha\machinelearning\test.py", line 22, in test_compute_Phi
>    Phi = compute_Phi(x,2)
>   File "C:\Users\visha\machinelearning\linear_regression.py", line 30, in compute_Phi
>   Phi[:,i] = np.power(x,i).reshape(x.shape[0],)
>   ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (3,1)

[code]

```
def compute_Phi(x,p):
    x = np.asmatrix(x)
    Phi = np.zeros(shape = (x.shape[0],p))
    for i in range(0,p):
        Phi[:,i] = np.power(x,i).reshape(x.shape[0],)
        Phi = np.asmatrix(Phi)
return Phi
```

Comment: Use `np.asarray(x)`.  Avoid `asmatrix`

Comment: what values are you passing for x and p

Comment: Hi @Dev, x is np.mat('1.;2.;3') and p is 2 in the test case.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, yeah I changed it but still gives me the same error.

Comment: You created `Phi` as 2d `ndarray`.  Why did you pass it through `np.matrix` in the loop?  `np.matrix` behave differently when indexed.  That produces confusion, which is part of why their use in new code is discouraged.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, There was a type error previously in the same problem statement when the asmatrix was not originally used, hence tried using it to negate that error. Can you please try running that code without the last asmatrix function and see the error that comes along? And can you please correct and paste the code here. I can then run it and see how it goes step by step.

Comment: @VishaV. That's literally your job.

Comment: `Phi[:,i]` produces a (3,) if `Phi` is `ndarray`, and (3,1) if `matrix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error is because in 1st iteration of for loop you Phi is np.array and in second iteration it is changed to matrix. It is working if you moved the line `Phi = np.asmatrix(Phi)` outside of the loop

```py
def compute_Phi(x,p):
    x = np.asmatrix(x)
    Phi = np.zeros(shape = (x.shape[0],p))
    Phi = np.asmatrix(Phi)
    for i in range(0,p):
        print(Phi[:,i])
        print(np.power(x,i))
        Phi[:,i] = np.power(x,i)

    return Phi 

compute_Phi(np.mat('1.;2.;3'), 2)
```

**Output**

```
matrix([[1., 1.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 3.]])
```

Comment: Hi @Dev, the above code you gave gives me a type error now instead of the broadcast error. It says that, assert type(Phi) ==np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix

Comment: @VishwaV at what line, the code is working for me, in python 3

Comment: @VishwaV may be your function caller expecting matrix type, change the return statement to "return np.asmatrix(Phi)"

Comment: That works, but it shouldn't be done as the given return statement should not be changed in the assignment. Can you tell me another way to implement your above idea?

Comment: I edited the answer above plz check if that works for your

Comment: Hi @Dev, yeah this works perfectly fine. The function caller expecting a matrix as output was the catch all along. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did, but it's not displaying publicly as my reputation is under 15.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x`, without the `np.mat`:

```
In [225]: x = np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]                                                
In [226]: x                                                                            
Out[226]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [227]: p = 2                                                                        
In [228]: Phi = np.zeros((3,2))                                                        
In [229]: Phi[:,0] = np.power(x,0)                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-229-f8ff29de133c> in <module>
----> 1 Phi[:,0] = np.power(x,0)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

Why?  `x` has shape (3,1) (as defined).  But `Phi[:,0]` has shape (3,).  By broadcasting rules the (3,1) can't be put in a (3,) space.  A (1,3) could.  A (3,) could.

Let's make `x` (3,):

```
In [230]: x = np.array([1,2,3])                                                        
In [231]: Phi[:,0] = np.power(x,0)                                                     
In [232]: Phi[:,1] = np.power(x,1)                                                     
In [233]: Phi                                                                          
Out[233]: 
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 2.],
       [1., 3.]])
```

Now we can assign the columns.

Now the (3,1) shape `x` can work with multiple powers at once:

```
In [234]: np.power(x[:,None],[0,1,2,3])                                                
Out[234]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  4,  8],
       [ 1,  3,  9, 27]])
```

Here the (3,1) `x` broadcasts with a (4,) `p` to produce a (3,4) result.

The broadcasting steps are: (3,1), (4,) => (3,1), (1,4) => (3,4), (3,4)

The keys are - size 1 dimensions can be added automatically in the lead position.  And size 1 dimensions are scaled to match the others.